# How to keep the intersection of two borders?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im working on a maze generation webapp and i'm having troubling finding out how to render the generated maze. Its simple to create the grid, but when removing walls between cells im getting a square gap in the bottom corner of the cell where the two previous borders overlapped. Is there any way to make it so the bottom corner is always filled in?

```css
.container{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
}

.cell{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}


/* CODE THAT CAUSES ISSUE */
.c5{
  border-bottom: None;
  border-right: None;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell c5"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pseudo class ***:after***. Make your `.c5` `class position: relative` and then make your `.c5:after` pseudo class `position: absolute` set your ***bottom*** and ***right*** *positions* to ***0px*** and set a ***width*** and ***height*** the same as your border, ***10px***. It will place a 10px box over the bottom right corner of your div.

### ***EDIT:***

To make this more dynamic with changing sizes to your border, use a ***CSS variable*** to set the ***border-size*** on your maze elements, then use that same variable on your pseudo `::after` class for ***height*** and ***width***.

***Note on CSS variables:*** CSS variables can be declared *globally* (***:root*** element) or *locally* (***selector that is using it***). Since this will be used by multiple elements, declare it globally on the ***:root*** element, this way any of the roots children will have access to the variable.

[image: .c5::after]

*Javascript in snippit is purely for display purposes to show ability to change dynamically within the roots variable, all the changing is done inside the CSS*

```js
const root = document.documentElement

const input = root.querySelector('#border-size')

input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
if(e.target.value >= 3 && e.target.value < 25)
  root.style.setProperty('--maze-border', `${e.target.value}px`)
})
```

```css
/* Set the size of your border here then 
each relavent size will change dynamically */
:root {
  --maze-border: 5px;
}

p {
  width: 300px;
}

.container{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-top: var(--maze-border) solid black;
  border-left: var(--maze-border) solid black;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
}

.cell{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: var(--maze-border) solid black;
  border-right: var(--maze-border) solid black;
}


/* CODE THAT CAUSES ISSUE */
.c5{
  border-bottom: None;
  border-right: None;
  position: relative
}

.c5::after {
  content: '';
  width: var(--maze-border);
  height: var(--maze-border);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell c5"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Set a size for your border and the pseudo <i><b>::after</b></i> class selectors <b>height</b> and <b>width</b> rule will change <i>dynamically</i> to the variable value set in the root element for <b><i>--maze-border</i></b>: </p>
<input type="number" size="5" id="border-size"> Input has a greater than 3 and a less than 25 pixel size restraint
```

***--EDIT: Removed other example***

Comment: Sort of worked. Im getting weird overflow in only some of the corners now even though they are the same dimensions as the borders https://imgur.com/a/Udz9Bzj

Comment: Work's good at 10px, but overflows whenever I set px value lower than 10... weird

Comment: `but overflows whenever I set px value lower than 10` are you talking about the border pixel size? As long as you change the height and width of the pseudo class to match that of your border then it should work. Perhaps you can share the code that is not working? One way to make it more dynamic would be to check the border size of your *maze* using JS and set it to a root variable in CSS and then set your classes pseudo after tot he variable, that way when you change it in your main elements css it will change on your root elements css variable.

Comment: @ZacHolme see my updated snippit using a **root:** ***variable*** to set the *border size* in your CSS and then use that variable on the width and height of the ***el::after*** pseudo class. This way you only have to change one setting in your CSS and each element that uses that variable will change dynamically.